# React - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even though I already set the key

Tags: reactjs

I got the warning "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" while tried to map an array and returned JSX .

Here is the code I wrote:

```js
<select>
  {props.optionsList.length > 0 &&
    props.optionsList.map((option) => (
      <option
        value={option.value}
        disabled={option.disable ? true : false}
        key={option.id}
        selected={option.selected}
      >
        {option.textContent}
      </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Can anyone please show me how to fix this problem or show me what I did wrong? Thank you!

I'm aware that I need to set keys when rendering a list in React. And for most of the last cases, I did fine except for this case.

Comment: Are you sure the keys are _unique_?

Comment: Can you please show a sample dataset for `props.optionsList`?

Comment: It turned out my keys were null and undefined when my component was rendered at 1st & 2nd times. Hence got the warning. Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log(optionsList)` and see where is the issue. 
I see that you have the property `key` but this can happen if

1. `option` is undefined or null
2. `option.id` is undefined or null
3. some items have the same `id`

However you can use the second parameter of the `map` function to have always an unique `key`:

```js
{
  props.optionsList.length > 0 &&
    props.optionsList.map((option,index) => (
      <option
        value={option.value}
        disabled={option.disable ? true : false}
        key={index}
        selected={option.selected}
      >
        {option.textContent}
      </option>
    ));
}
```

but you should find first what is causing this warning because using `key ={option.id}` is recommanded and should work if there is no problem

Comment: If the items in the list are changed, using the index as the key would be incorrect, because React won't know what to compare what to.

Comment: I would add using index as a kind of failsafe `key={option.id + "-" + index}`

Comment: @code - if the items in the list are changed then my understanding is the whole list would re-render anyway. Using `index` is more just a failsafe in case `id` isn't defined or unique.

Comment: @JohnDetlefs indeed, but it shouldn't be used by itself.

Comment: @Ahamed Sbai,  it turned out my component was rendered 3 times and at the 1st & 2nd render the component received null key. Thank you your help.