# "Unable to locate to the origin of the key props" warning, related the React Router v6's Route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered this error that prompted in my console. I don't know which list is causing this error. May I know is there a way that I can track back the origin of this error, so I know where to solve the error?

I am using the React Router component which implements the list. That is why it needs a key props.

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `IndexRouter`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={LazyLoad("login/Login")} />
  <Route path="/app" element={LazyLoad("sandbox/Sandbox")}>
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate to={"home"} />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />
    {routeList.map((item) => {
      if (checkPagePermission(item) && checkUserPermission(item)) {
        return (
          <Route
            path={item.key.slice(1)}
            key={item.key.slice(1)}
            element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])}</AuthComponent>}
          />
        );
      }
      return <Route path="*" element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />
          //Use return null instead  
    })}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={"/app"} />} />
  <Route path="*" element={LazyLoad("notFound/NotFound")} />
</Routes>
```

<s>So, I managed to solve the error by adding the key for the "Route" in the "if case", as well as the "noPermission route".</s>

I think I am putting some useless extra effort here. I should directly return null instead of returning the noPermission route again.

Comment: Isn't `IndexRouter.js` file at line 34 related ?

Comment: There is no way for us to help without seeing the code that produces the error. But this error is generally quite clear, you either have no `key`s on some listed components, or the `key`s are not unique.

Comment: I attached the code ya, thank you.

Comment: The loop over `routeList` (inside the `IndexRouter` component) should be the origin of the complaints. At first glance, those generated `Route`s inside that loop should be assigned a unique `key` to each one of them.

Comment: I gave a key to them previously for each route by using this key={item.key.slice(1)}. But the error still persisted. I updated the code and also the structure of routeList as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even though I already set the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639781/react-warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-even-thoug)

Comment: This did not answer my question. It is a different scenario, and he has a problem with the Rendering process. My issue is different, which is missing the key props in the route components, which I will find out later. Everything inside the .map() should have a key to prevent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```js
{
  routeList.map((item) => {
    if (checkPagePermission(item) && checkUserPermission(item)) {
      return <Route path={item.key.slice(1)} key={item.key.slice(1)} element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])}</AuthComponent>} />;
    }
    return <Route path="*" element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />;
  })
}
```

you return `<Route path="*" ...` for each item when the permission checks fail.

You have no `key` for those. Adding the `path={item.key.slice(1)}` should fix it.

---

so

```js
{
  routeList.map((item) => {
    if (checkPagePermission(item) && checkUserPermission(item)) {
      return <Route path={item.key.slice(1)} key={item.key.slice(1)} element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])}</AuthComponent>} />;
    }
    return <Route path="*" key={item.key.slice(1)} element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />;
  })
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue, the error is not longer showing. Thanks

Comment: @Marcus just a note. It does not seem to make much sense to return multiple routes with `path="*"`. Perhaps you could just return `null` in those cases.

Comment: @Gabirele, thank you for clarifying that issue; I think it is just some useless extra effort I put in here. I updated the code to return null

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solve the error by adding the key for the "Route" in the "if case", as well as the "noPermission route"

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to your answer?